# MySQL to MongoDB conversion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

How do I convert the following into MongoDB query ?

```
sets_progress = Photo.select('count(status) as count, status, photoset_id')
                     .where('photoset_id IN (?)', sets_tracked_array)
                     .group('photoset_id, status')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 1 to 1 mapping of a SQL query to a NoSQL implementation. You'll need to precalculate your data to match the way you want to access that data.

If it is small enough, then this query will need to change into a map-reduce job. More here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Here's a decent tutorial that takes a query that GROUP's and converts to map-reduce: http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial/